# How to refresh dropdown when user back and previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

When select data  in dropdown list and click submit or save (Redirect to another page)

Then click back or previous every browser like IE , Chrome , Firefox , Data in dropdown list have remember the latest information did you select ....

> The question is how to clear or reset that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops ... i found answer in this link  http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/03/how-to-reset-dropdown-using-jquery.html

Below code will find the first item in the list and make it selected.
1

> $('#DropDownList1').find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');

Below code will find the item with value o and selects it. If the first item in your dropdown list starts with -1, then use -1 as argument.
1

> $('#DropDownList1').val(0);

Below jQuery code will set the very first item of the list as selected.
1

> $('#DropDownList1 option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected');

Below jQuery code will set selectedindex of dropdown list to 0, which is the first item of the dropdown list.
1

> $('#DropDownList1').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;

If you know any other way to reset the dropdown then please let us know. We will add your code in this list and also give credit you for the same.